# Debian never use router gateway address in resolv.conf

Tags: dns, debian

Debian never use router gateway address in resolv.conf

How could I setup Debian to (never use router as Domain Name resolver)does not display the router gateway address (nameserver 192.168.1.1) in /etc/resolv.conf when I restart the computer or execute `/sbin/dhclient`?

I use only one line in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
prepend domain-name-servers x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y,z.z.z.z;
```

This is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

> ```
>  auto eth0 
>  iface eth0 inet static
>
>  address 192.168.1.170
>  netmask 255.255.255.0
>  network 192.168.1.0
>  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>  getaway 192.168.1.1
>  up route add -net default gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 eth0
>
>  dns-nameservers x.x.x.x y.y.y.y z.z.z.z
> ```

If I run
/sbin/dhclient
/etc/init.d/networking restart

my /etc/resolv.conf contains:

```
nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver y.y.y.y
nameserver z.z.z.z
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: I know this is old, but, gateway is spelled incorrectly, thus perhaps precipitating the redundant (but not really because of the misspelling) gateway parameter in the up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please clean up your configuration. Is your `eth0` interface supposed to be configured with a static IP address or with DHCP? If static, why are you running `dhclient`? If DHCP, why does `/etc/network/interfaces` list static IP parameters and `iface eth0 inet static` instead of `iface eth0 inet dhcp`? Also, there is no reason you would need to add a default route via your `up route` command since you already specified the default route as the `gateway` parameter.

Now keep in mind that as per the name, `prepend domain-name-servers` adds DNS servers to the list that is supplied by the DHCP server. It doesn't replace them.

I recommend that, instead of asking `dhclient` to customize the name servers you want to use, use the `resolvconf` framework instead. `resolvconf` coordinates all of the different possible sources of DNS nameserver information (including separate DHCP clients running on one or more network interfaces, local DNS servers you want to use as resolvers, and static configuration) and centralized the building of a single coherent `/etc/resolv.conf` file. It's much better than letting several different things manage `/etc/resolv.conf` and have them stomp over each other trying to do it.

Install the `resolvconf` package if it isn't already installed. This will automatically disable `dhclinent`'s direct mucking with the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Now your requirement is that you don't want to use the nameserver(s) provided by the DHCP server, so comment the line that reads `eth*` in `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order`. Be sure to also comment the last line of the file that reads `*`, otherwise `eth0` will still be considered.

Next, you want to use a set of statically provisioned nameservers instead. Since they're system-global (not related to the state if any given interface), you can add them as nameservers on the lo interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface lo inet loopback
    dns-nameservers x.x.x.x y.y.y.y z.z.z.z
```

And then `ifdown lo; ifup lo` to activate this.

Answer (score 2):

One other point:  g**eta**way 192.168.1.1 should be  g**ate**way 192.168.1.1 (which is probably why you have had to add the default route in order to get anything working?)

Answer (score 0):

If you can possibly avoid it, don't use your gateway as a resolver at all.

They're notoriously buggy at doing DNS proxying - see RFC 5625.

You have a perfectly functional Linux box - just drop a copy of BIND or even better "Unbound" on it.

ObDisclaimer - I wrote that RFC.